# MongoDB reactive template transactions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, transactions, kotlinx.coroutines

I've been using mongodb for my open source project for more than a year now and recently I decided to try out the transactions. After writing some tests for methods that use transactions I figured out that they throw some strange exceptions and I can't figure out what is the problem. So I have a [method](https://github.com/K1rakishou/photoexchange-backend/blob/2d91c3d32a22e69f03b91f42ef2094f981884ebc/src/main/kotlin/com/kirakishou/photoexchange/database/repository/PhotoInfoRepository.kt#L328) `delete` that uses custom `coroutine context` and a `mutex`:

```
  open suspend fun delete(photoInfo: PhotoInfo): Boolean {
    return withContext(coroutineContext) {
      return@withContext mutex.withLock {
        return@withLock deletePhotoInternalInTransaction(photoInfo)
      }
    }
  }
```

It then calls a [method](https://github.com/K1rakishou/photoexchange-backend/blob/2d91c3d32a22e69f03b91f42ef2094f981884ebc/src/main/kotlin/com/kirakishou/photoexchange/database/repository/PhotoInfoRepository.kt#L338) that executes some deletion:

```
  //FIXME: doesn't work in tests
  //should be called from within locked mutex
  private suspend fun deletePhotoInternalInTransaction(photoInfo: PhotoInfo): Boolean {
    check(!photoInfo.isEmpty())

    val transactionMono = template.inTransaction().execute { txTemplate ->
      return@execute photoInfoDao.deleteById(photoInfo.photoId, txTemplate)
        .flatMap { favouritedPhotoDao.deleteFavouriteByPhotoName(photoInfo.photoName, txTemplate) }
        .flatMap { reportedPhotoDao.deleteReportByPhotoName(photoInfo.photoName, txTemplate) }
        .flatMap { locationMapDao.deleteById(photoInfo.photoId, txTemplate) }
        .flatMap { galleryPhotoDao.deleteByPhotoName(photoInfo.photoName, txTemplate) }
    }.next()

    return try {
      transactionMono.awaitFirst()
      true
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
      logger.error("Could not delete photo", error)
      false
    }
  }
```

Here I have five operations that delete data from five different documents. Here is an example of one of the operations:

```
open fun deleteById(photoId: Long, template: ReactiveMongoOperations = reactiveTemplate): Mono<Boolean> {
    val query = Query()
      .addCriteria(Criteria.where(PhotoInfo.Mongo.Field.PHOTO_ID).`is`(photoId))

    return template.remove(query, PhotoInfo::class.java)
      .map { deletionResult -> deletionResult.wasAcknowledged() }
      .doOnError { error -> logger.error("DB error", error) }
      .onErrorReturn(false)
  }
```

I want this operation to fail if either of deletions fails so I use a transaction.

Then I have some [tests](https://github.com/K1rakishou/photoexchange-backend/blob/2d91c3d32a22e69f03b91f42ef2094f981884ebc/src/test/kotlin/com/kirakishou/photoexchange/handlers/UploadPhotoHandlerTest.kt#L72) for a handler that uses this `delete` method:

```
  @Test
  fun `photo should not be uploaded if could not enqueue static map downloading request`() {
    val webClient = getWebTestClient()
    val userId = "1234235236"
    val token = "fwerwe"

    runBlocking {
      Mockito.`when`(remoteAddressExtractorService.extractRemoteAddress(any())).thenReturn(ipAddress)
      Mockito.`when`(banListRepository.isBanned(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(false)
      Mockito.`when`(userInfoRepository.accountExists(userId)).thenReturn(true)
      Mockito.`when`(userInfoRepository.getFirebaseToken(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(token)
      Mockito.`when`(staticMapDownloaderService.enqueue(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(false)
    }

    kotlin.run {
      val packet = UploadPhotoPacket(33.4, 55.2, userId, true)
      val multipartData = createTestMultipartFile(PHOTO1, packet)

      val content = webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/v1/api/upload")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartData))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().is5xxServerError
        .expectBody()

      val response = fromBodyContent<UploadPhotoResponse>(content)
      assertEquals(ErrorCode.DatabaseError.value, response.errorCode)

      assertEquals(0, findAllFiles().size)

      runBlocking {
        assertEquals(0, galleryPhotoDao.testFindAll().awaitFirst().size)
        assertEquals(0, photoInfoDao.testFindAll().awaitFirst().size)
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun `photo should not be uploaded when resizeAndSavePhotos throws an exception`() {
    val webClient = getWebTestClient()
    val userId = "1234235236"
    val token = "fwerwe"

    runBlocking {
      Mockito.`when`(remoteAddressExtractorService.extractRemoteAddress(any())).thenReturn(ipAddress)
      Mockito.`when`(banListRepository.isBanned(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(false)
      Mockito.`when`(userInfoRepository.accountExists(userId)).thenReturn(true)
      Mockito.`when`(userInfoRepository.getFirebaseToken(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(token)
      Mockito.`when`(staticMapDownloaderService.enqueue(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(true)

      Mockito.doThrow(IOException("BAM"))
        .`when`(diskManipulationService).resizeAndSavePhotos(any(), any())
    }

    kotlin.run {
      val packet = UploadPhotoPacket(33.4, 55.2, userId, true)
      val multipartData = createTestMultipartFile(PHOTO1, packet)

      val content = webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/v1/api/upload")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartData))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().is5xxServerError
        .expectBody()

      val response = fromBodyContent<UploadPhotoResponse>(content)
      assertEquals(ErrorCode.ServerResizeError.value, response.errorCode)

      assertEquals(0, findAllFiles().size)

      runBlocking {
        assertEquals(0, galleryPhotoDao.testFindAll().awaitFirst().size)
        assertEquals(0, photoInfoDao.testFindAll().awaitFirst().size)
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun `photo should not be uploaded when copyDataBuffersToFile throws an exception`() {
    val webClient = getWebTestClient()
    val userId = "1234235236"
    val token = "fwerwe"

    runBlocking {
      Mockito.`when`(remoteAddressExtractorService.extractRemoteAddress(any())).thenReturn(ipAddress)
      Mockito.`when`(banListRepository.isBanned(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(false)
      Mockito.`when`(userInfoRepository.accountExists(userId)).thenReturn(true)
      Mockito.`when`(userInfoRepository.getFirebaseToken(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(token)
      Mockito.`when`(staticMapDownloaderService.enqueue(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(true)

      Mockito.doThrow(IOException("BAM"))
        .`when`(diskManipulationService).copyDataBuffersToFile(Mockito.anyList(), any())
    }

    kotlin.run {
      val packet = UploadPhotoPacket(33.4, 55.2, userId, true)
      val multipartData = createTestMultipartFile(PHOTO1, packet)

      val content = webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/v1/api/upload")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartData))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().is5xxServerError
        .expectBody()

      val response = fromBodyContent<UploadPhotoResponse>(content)
      assertEquals(ErrorCode.ServerDiskError.value, response.errorCode)

      assertEquals(0, findAllFiles().size)

      runBlocking {
        assertEquals(0, galleryPhotoDao.testFindAll().awaitFirst().size)
        assertEquals(0, photoInfoDao.testFindAll().awaitFirst().size)
      }
    }
  }
```

Usually the first test passes:

[image]

and the following two fail with the following exception:

```
17:09:01.228 [Thread-17] ERROR com.kirakishou.photoexchange.database.dao.PhotoInfoDao - DB error
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 24 (LockTimeout): 'Unable to acquire lock '{8368122972467948263: Database, 1450593944826866407}' within a max lock request timeout of '5ms' milliseconds.' on server 192.168.99.100:27017.
```

And then:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 246 (SnapshotUnavailable): 'Unable to read from a snapshot due to pending collection catalog changes; please retry the operation. Snapshot timestamp is Timestamp(1545661357, 23). Collection minimum is Timestamp(1545661357, 24)' on server 192.168.99.100:27017.
```

And:

```
17:22:36.951 [Thread-16] WARN  reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen - Async resource cleanup failed after cancel
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction): 'Transaction 1 has been aborted.' on server 192.168.99.100:27017.
```

Sometimes two of them pass and the last one fails.

[image]

It looks like only the first transaction succeeds and any following will fail and I guess the reason is that I have to manually close it (or the ClientSession). But I can't find any info on how to close transactions/sessions. [Here](https://github.com/christophstrobl/mongodb-bookstore/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/bookstore/reactive/transaction/ReactiveOrderService.java#L57) is one of the few examples I could find where they use transactions with reactive template and I don't see them doing anything additional to close transaction/session.

Or maybe it's because I'm mocking a method to throw an exception inside the transaction? Maybe it's not being closed in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client sessions/tranactions are closed properly however it appears the indexes creation in tests are acquiring global lock causes the next transaction lock to fall behind and wait before timing out on the lock request.

Basically you have to manage your index creation so they don’t interfere with transaction from client.

One quick fix would be to increase the lock timeout by running below command in shell.

db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis: 50 } )

In production you can look at the transaction error label 
and retry the operation.

More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions-production-consideration/#pending-ddl-operations-and-transactions

Answer (score 0):

You could check connection [options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options) and accord you [driver](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/api/reactivemongo/api/MongoConnection.html)

```
val connection = MongoConnection(List("localhost"))
val db = connection.database("plugin")
...
connection.askClose()
```

you could search method askClose(), hope you can helpfull

Comment: I'm using Spring mongodb driver and it doesn't return me back any connections (I guess the driver does it all internally). I do all work via ReactiveMongoTemplate and it doesn't even have any methods for returning connection or closing it.